# Is there any right way to get a file by its Path?

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I've two files with the same name in *KnownFolders.VideosLibrary*, in this case I cannot access file by its *Name* hence it will return only the first one. Therefore is there any other way to get the file other that parsing all files in folder?

```cs
// this return two files 
var files = (await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFilesAsync()).Where(x => x.Name == "test.txt").ToArray();
// with this I can get only one file
StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFileAsync("test.txt");
// of course I can parse it with query, but I would like to avoid it
// StorageFile myFile = (await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFilesAsync()).FirstOrDefault(x => x.FolderRelativeId == "something");
```

I'm aware of [FutureAccessList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemaccesslist), but it can hold only up to 1000 files, what is not enough for me.

---

**Some clarification after request:**

For example lets consider that app run on phone with SD card. I've one file in *Videos* in phone's memory with name `test.txt`, the file with the same name exists also on SD card in *Videos* folder.

In this situation when you call the first line in code above, you will get two files, to differentiate them system provides *FolderRelativeId*, so files with the same name can exist in one 'location'. If you take a look at the full path of each folder one will likely have `C:\Viedos\test.txt` and the second `D:\Videos\test.txt`.

Now user on the first run picked a file with *FilePicker* and I've remembered its path for example `D:\Videos\test.txt`. On the second run of the app I would like to have access to this file by using its path (or other method apart from limited *FutureAccessList*). In the past I used to do it by `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);` - by it seems that it [starts throwing *UnauthorizedAccessException* in W10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33908055/2681948).

Comment: why just don't use loop for each file in files? what is type of files (your variable)? The second thing is I wonder how it's possible to have 2 files with the same name

Comment: @TomaszPikć It's a performance drawback if have to use a look when I know file's path, imagine when I have a directory with 1000 files and I 've to perform few file operations. As for the second thing - libraries are virtual locations and it's quite easy to have to same files - you can for example in Videos on phone's memory and on sd card have files with the same name, then in VideosLibrary they will have same name, but different relativefolderid.

Comment: "Therefore is there any other way to get the file other that parsing all files in folder?" - You already answered your question. `StorageFilder.GetFileAsync` will return the file you're searching for. If this isn't what you're looking for, please specify your question more.

Comment: @Herdo I've edited the question to add more clarification. Tell me if you need more.

Comment: Your code will return all files that have the given name. I don't see how you can do anything other than iterate over them, unless you know other info about the file, like the path, create date, size, or whatever.

Comment: @TonyVitabile I know the exact path of the file, for example `C:\Videos\test.txt`, though lets say that I cannot assume that it belongs to *VideosLibrary*. Simply, now *GetFileFromPathAsync()* throws exception - so I'm looking for other methods. Moreover - I can know everything of the file as it has been picked for the first time. Now on second run of the app I would like to access that file without prompting the user again.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the instance of `IStorageFile` by this.

```
// If your have a StorageFile objece file then 
//fileUri = new Uri(file.Path);

string uri = fileUri.LocalPath;
int end = uri.LastIndexOf('\\');
uri = uri.Substring(0, end + 1);

string name = Path.GetFileName(fileUri.LocalPath);
var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(uri);
IStorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(name);
// Do something with file object
```

Comment: I've some doubts if it will work - for the same reason - privileges.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188703.aspx) documentation from MS, that apps *can **opt out** of allowing files to be stored on the SD card. As a result, the media libraries can be **split across the device's internal storage and the SD card**.*

If I get this right, your solution would be:

- Opt out the feature mentioned above
- You should now only search on the local device, not the SD card

  - This will result in unique file names in each directory
- If your use-case requires to search for the file on SD cards as well, you now have to [access the SD card](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188699.aspx), and query the file here

I'm not sure, if the coding overhead of accessing the SD card separately, if worth the performance gain by only querying the local storage.

Comment: I cannot opt out splitting the library as it doesn't depend on me - the user decides where he will store files. Also, as I've understood you opt for searching a file, and I would like to avoid this as I already know where file exists via it's path. The problem is that *StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path)* doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file with a file picker in a Windows 8.1 app (I'm assuming Windows 10 works the same way) you are obtaining a rights token to that folder that lasts for a period of time, or until you quit the application.  When you reopen the application, you have to re-obtain a token to the folder.

Read this article about the [`StorageApplicationPermissions`](http://Here's%20the%20object%20you%20are%20looking%20for:) object.

Comment: The problem is how to re-obtain that token. In W/WP8.1 it was possible to do it via StorageFile.GetFileFromPath, in W10 it throws exception. Therefore I'm looking for other possibilities.

Comment: what's the exception that it throws?

Comment: You're right @Romasz, that behavior has changed in Windows 10, even from an 8.1 app.  I guess we'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: What you can do is remember the file before quitting the app. You get a string token for it using StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.Add( storageFile). Later on you can get the file back using StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.GetFileAsync( stringToken). Put the token into LocalSettings. Note there is a limit on how many you can keep in MostRecentlyUsedList, so if you are doing this over and over you will have to Clear() the list.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one could rationalize the `UnauthorizedAccessException` thrown when calling `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path)` by considering that you don't have access to a root drive letter from your app, so navigating the folder structure that way is not allowed. It's a guess though.

As for your problem, why aren't you able to do this?

```
var file = (await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFilesAsync()).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Path == "D:\Videos\test.txt");
```

Where `D:\Videos\test.txt` is the `.Path` property value that you grabbed from the file that the user selected using the picker.

Perhaps you can expect it to be a little slower when there are millions of files on the VideosLibrary.

Comment: Seems like you are proposing the same method like the one I've commented out in my code in question. I would like to avoid parsing the folder. As a side note, it was possible in 8.1 but seems like in UWP it has changed cause of security reasons.